# How can I change an int array in a function

Tags: c, arrays, function

Im new with c language and im having difficult while trying to change an array on my main function using another function. Besides seeing the solution I'd also like to get a full explanation what is wrong with my code and what's the explanation to your solution.

OK so I did too much tryouts and error experimentation but with no success to solve my problem. Eventually this is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 20
typedef int Values[MAX];

int changeArr(Values *vals2) 
{
    *vals2[0] = 200;
    *vals2[1] = 100;
    printf("%d and ", *vals2[0]);
    printf("%d\n", *vals2[1]);
    return 0;
}   

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    Values vals;
    changeArr(&vals);
    printf("%d and ", vals[0]);
    printf("%d\n", vals[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
200 and 100
200 and 0
```

Instead of:

```
200 and 100
200 and 100
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Version 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 20
typedef int Values[MAX];

int changeArr(int vals2[]) {
    vals2[0] = 200;
    vals2[1] = 100;
    printf("%d and ", vals2[0]);
    printf("%d\n", vals2[1]);
    return 0;
}   

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Values vals;
    changeArr(vals);
    printf("%d and ", vals[0]);
    printf("%d\n", vals[1]);
    return 0;

}
```

Instead of passing a pointer to the array, pass a pointer to the array's first element.

Version 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 20
typedef int Values[MAX];

int changeArr(Values *vals2) {
    (*vals2)[0] = 200;
    (*vals2)[1] = 100;
    printf("%d and ", (*vals2)[0]);
    printf("%d\n", (*vals2)[1]);
    return 0;
}   

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Values vals;
    changeArr(&vals);
    printf("%d and ", vals[0]);
    printf("%d\n", vals[1]);
    return 0;

}
```

use parentheses to compensate for the precedence.

The problem in your code is that

```
*vals2[1]
```

is `*(vals2[1])`, so it dereferences a pointer one unit of `Values` after the passed pointer. You have no accessible memory allocated there, so it's undefined behaviour. In practice, it is the same as accessing

```
arr[1][0]
```

for an

```
int arr[2][MAX];
```

But your `vals` is only (equivalent to) an `int arr[1][MAX];`, so you are accessing out of bounds. But if nothing worse happens, `*vals2[1] = 100;` in `changeArr` sets `vals[MAX]` in `main` to 100. It may overwrite something crucial, though.

In `int changeArr(Values *vals2)` you are passing a pointer to an array of `MAX` `int`s, resp the first such array in an array of `Values`. Then `vals2[1]` is the second array in that array of `Values` (which doesn't exist here), and `*vals2[1] == vals2[1][0]` the first `int` in that second array. You want to modify elements of the first (and only) array in the pointed-to memory block, so you want to access `vals2[0][1]`, or equivalently `(*vals2)[1]`.

A picture:

```
vals2                          vals2[1]
 |                               |
 v                               v
|vals[0]|vals[1]|...|vals[MAX-1]|x
```

in `changeArr`, the pointer `vals2` points to the array `vals`. Since it's a pointer to an `int[MAX]`, `vals2+1` points to an `int[MAX]` at an offset of `MAX*sizeof(int)` bytes after the start of `vals` (which is just behind the end of `vals`). `vals2[1]`, or equivalently `*(vals2 + 1)`, is that array just after `vals` (which doesn't exist).

You want to change `vals[1]`, which is located in the array `vals2[0]`, at an offset of `1*sizeof(int)` bytes, so you need `vals2[0][1]` or equivalently `(*vals2)[1]`.

Comment: First thank you for ur detailed answer! i am trying to implement the main idea and by re-reading your explanation and looking at my entire code (which is doing much more logic), another question comes up: what if i am doing another use of a function in the changeArr() function, for example the function fscanf() - which writes a value from file to a certain index in the values array, how am i supposed to send that pointed array? fscanf(file, "%d", (*vals2)([0]) causes the error: warning: format argument is not a pointer..

Comment: In that case, when you want to `fscanf` into the `i`-th element of the array, you can take its address, `fscanf("%d", &(*vals2)[i]);` or you can avoid the dereferencing implied by `[i]` and pass `fscanf("%d", (*vals2)+i)`. But I prefer taking the address, `fscanf("%d", &object);` uniformly, regardless of whether the object is an ordinary `int` variable or an array element.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! This is definitely the best explanation iv'e received over this website. As a student who's new with C i'm sure this post will help many others. Anyway, though u left me speechless I'll use this opportunity ask: (1) in theory, is there any difference from version 1 to version 2 codes? (2) is there any easy way to loop such values array until the last index that was assigned (in other words, lets say the array is 10 size and only 3 were assigned and i want to loop only these three elements) ?

Comment: (1) Yes, there is a difference. In version 1, the function receives an `int*`, it does not know how large the array that it points into is, and the type can't document how large an array is expected. In version 2, the function receives an `int (*)[20]`, so it knows precisely how many elements `*vals2` has - but it doesn't know a block of how many `int[20]` the argument `vals2` itself points to. For what the function does, I think version 1 is more appropriate, though it would be better to pass also a size argument so that the function doesn't access elements that don't exist.

Comment: (2) Basically, you have to have a size argument/return/out parameter telling whoever receives it how many elements there are to be considered. In some cases, you can mark the end with a sentinel value (as is done for C strings with the 0-terminator, but in general, 0 is a valid entry in a `char[]`, so you can't use that for other uses of character arrays), but a size parameter is more universally applicable.