# changing array in a function c

Tags: c, pointers

I was doing some exercises on pointer in C , because I have some problems with them. I have to change some values in an array using a void function , but when I run the code it returns me a segfault.
Here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void change( int **v , int l ) {

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < l ; i++ ) 
                 *v[i] = 0 ;

 }

 int main ( int argc , char** argv ) {

           int *v , l ;
           scanf("%d",&l) ;
           v = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*l) ;

           for ( int i = 0 ; i < l ; i++ ) 
                    scanf("%d",&v[i]) ;

           change( &v , l ) ;

           for ( int i = 0 ; i < l ; i++ ) 
               printf("%d ",v[i]) ;

           return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: The reason for using as an argument `int **v` What?

Comment: `*v[i]` --> `(*v)[i]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
void change( int **v , int l )
```

to

```
void change( int *v , int l )
```

then

```
*v[i] = 0 ;
```

to

```
 v[i] = 0 ;
```

then

```
change( &v , l ) ;
```

to

```
change( v , l ) ;
```

You don't need to use a pointer to a pointer to `int` to change an array element, just pass a pointer to the first of the element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 20
typedef int Values[MAX];

int changeArr(int vals2[]) {
    vals2[0] = 200;
    vals2[1] = 100;
    printf("%d and ", vals2[0]);
    printf("%d\n", vals2[1]);
    return 0;
}   

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Values vals;
    changeArr(vals);
    printf("%d and ", vals[0]);
    printf("%d\n", vals[1]);
    return 0;

}
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 20
typedef int Values[MAX];

int changeArr(Values *vals2) {
    (*vals2)[0] = 200;
    (*vals2)[1] = 100;
    printf("%d and ", (*vals2)[0]);
    printf("%d\n", (*vals2)[1]);
    return 0;
}   

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Values vals;
    changeArr(&vals);
    printf("%d and ", vals[0]);
    printf("%d\n", vals[1]);
    return 0;

}
```

Source : [How can I change an int array in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003626/how-can-i-change-an-int-array-in-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Just make your code works, the minimal change of your code is change `*v[i] = 0 ;` to `(*v)[i] = 0 ;`